# CodenameOne: DialogBody leaves too much space in CodenameOne 4.x compared to 3.x versions

Tags: codenameone

Between one version of CodenameOne and the most recent, the DialogBody of a Dialog has become much larger and leaves excessive space below its content.  I'm currently using version 4.4 in IntelliJ.
Here's an example (but all my dialogs now seem to have the same issue):

The code that generates the dialog:

```
Dialog.show("Quit this test?", "Do you really want to quit this test and discard your progress?", "Quit", "Return to Test")
```

[image: Normal Dialog from a 3.x version of codenameOne (Don't recall which precisely)]

[image: This is what it looks like built with a 4.x version of CodenameOne]

Comment: I was able to reproduce this and it does look weird. I'll try to take a deeper look at it later to see what's going on. Please file an issue on this so it doesn't get lost

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be be a regression due to a recent change. We found the lines in the code that are responsible for it and it should be fixed before 5.0 is released. This issue is tracked here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2536